# TimeDistributed with LSTM in keyword spotter

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, speech-recognition

I am working on a keyword spotter that processes an audio input and returns the class of the audio based on a list of speech commands similar to what is shown here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/simple_audio

Instead of processing only 1 second of audio as input, I would like to be able to process multiple frames of audio, say 5 time steps with a 10ms step and feed them into the machine learning model.

In essence, this amounts to adding a `TimeDistributed` layer on top of my network.
The second thing I am trying to do is to add an LSTM layer prior to the dense layer that maps my hidden layers to the output classes.

**My question**: How can I effectively change the code below to add a `TimeDistributed` layer that takes in multiple time steps and an LSTM layer.

Started code:

```py
model = models.Sequential([
    layers.Input(shape=input_shape),
    preprocessing.Resizing(32, 32), 
    norm_layer,
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Dropout(0.25),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Dense(num_labels),
])
```

Model summary:

```
Input shape: (124, 129, 1)
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
resizing (Resizing)          (None, 32, 32, 1)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
normalization (Normalization (None, 32, 32, 1)         3         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 30, 30, 32)        320       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 14, 14, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 14, 14, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 12544)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 128)               1605760   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 8)                 1032      
=================================================================
Total params: 1,625,611
Trainable params: 1,625,608
Non-trainable params: 3
_________________________________________________________________
```

**Attempt1**: Adding an LSTM layer

```py
model = models.Sequential([
    layers.Input(shape=input_shape),
    preprocessing.Resizing(32, 32), 
    norm_layer,
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Dropout(0.25),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.LSTM(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,128,98)),
    layers.Dense(num_labels),
])
```

Error: `ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_5 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 128]`

**Attempt2**: Adding a TimeDistributed layer:

```py
model = models.Sequential([
    layers.Input(shape=input_shape),
    preprocessing.Resizing(32, 32), 
    norm_layer,
    TimeDistributed(layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'), input_shape=(None, 32, 32, 1)),
    TimeDistributed(layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'), input_shape=(None, 30, 30, 1)),
    TimeDistributed(layers.MaxPooling2D()),
    TimeDistributed(layers.Dropout(0.25)),
    TimeDistributed(layers.Flatten()),
    TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')),
    TimeDistributed(layers.Dropout(0.5)),
    TimeDistributed(layers.Flatten()),
    layers.Dense(num_labels),
])
```

Error: `ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_43 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 32, 1]`

I understand there is a problem with my dimensions. I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LSTM` layer expects inputs: A 3D tensor with shape `[batch, timesteps, feature]`
**Sample code snippet**

```
import tensorflow as tf
inputs = tf.random.normal([32, 10, 8])
lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4)
output = lstm(inputs)
print(output.shape)
```

`tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed` expects inputs: Input tensor of shape `(batch, time, ...)`

**Working sample code**

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10, 128, 128, 3))
conv_2d_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3))
outputs = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(conv_2d_layer)(inputs)
outputs.shape
```